# Not able to import CSV file in MySQL Workbench through load data local infile query

Tags: mysql-workbench

I was trying to import a CSV file into MySQL Workbench through "load data local infile" query, but I am getting Error Code 3948 while running that query.

- **Import Query:**

```
load data local infile 'D:/Learning/DataSets/Customertbl.csv'
into table w3school_db.customer
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 rows
(`CustomerName`,`ContactName`,`Address`,`City`,`PostalCode`,`Country`);
```

**Error which I am getting in log:**

> Error Code 3948: Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and sever sides.

Comment: I find question posts work better when there is an explicit question in the post body. Please see [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)